# Python/Pandas Regex for a Wide Variety of Dates

Tags: python, regex, pandas, date

I have a task to extract a wide variety of dates from a text file using Python.

As per the requirements, the following date formats must be properly extracted from the text file:

- 04/20/2009; 04/20/09; 4/20/09; 4/3/09
- Mar-20-2009; Mar 20, 2009; March 20, 2009; Mar. 20, 2009; Mar 20 2009;
- 20 Mar 2009; 20 March 2009; 20 Mar. 2009; 20 March, 2009
- Mar 20th, 2009; Mar 21st, 2009; Mar 22nd, 2009
- Feb 2009; Sep 2009; Oct 2010 *(shall be parsed to 02/01/2009, 09/01/2009 etc)*
- 6/2008; 12/2009 *(shall be parsed to 06/01/2008 etc).*
- 2009; 2010 *(shall be parsed to 01/01/2009 and 01/01/2010)*

**Regex to the rescue!**

Came up with the following expression:

```
(((0?[1-9]|1[0-2])((\/)|(-)))?(((0?[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])((\/)|(-))))((19[0-9][0-9])|(20[0-1]{1}[0-9])|([0-9][0-9]))|((19[0-9][0-9])|(20[0-1]{1}[0-9])))|((0[1-9])|(1[0-9])|(2[0-9])|(3[0-1]))?(\D)?(Jan(uary)?|Feb(ruary)?|Mar(ch)?|Apr(il)?|May|Jun(e)?|Jul(y)?|Aug(ust)?|Sep(tember)?|Oct(ober)?|Nov(ember)?|Dec(ember)?)((\s|\.|-)((19[0-9][0-9])|(20[0-9][0-9])))
```

I was able to debug it with [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/OdSQza/1/) for all use cases.

However, when I try to run it over a Pandas dataframe using the code below, no matches are found for some of the cases - ("df" stands for a Pandas dataframe where each of the rows contains raw text with a date in one of the formats above)

```
import re

pattern = '(((0?[1-9]|1[0-2])((\/)|(-)))?(((0?[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])((\/)|(-))))((19[0-9][0-9])|(20[0-1]{1}[0-9])|([0-9][0-9]))|((19[0-9][0-9])|(20[0-1]{1}[0-9])))|((0[1-9])|(1[0-9])|(2[0-9])|(3[0-1]))?(\D)?(Jan(uary)?|Feb(ruary)?|Mar(ch)?|Apr(il)?|May|Jun(e)?|Jul(y)?|Aug(ust)?|Sep(tember)?|Oct(ober)?|Nov(ember)?|Dec(ember)?)((\s|\.|-)((19[0-9][0-9])|(20[0-9][0-9])))'

flags = re.IGNORECASE

m = df.str.extract(pattern, flags)
```

Cases where there's not a match include:

1. A**Feb 1977**: Symmes Hospital\n
2. "NV fire fighter died **Sep 2007** while working.  Was friend from deployment to San Marino and trainings for years prior.  Still troubling to pt.  Didn't go to his funeral.  Spiritual/Religion:\n
3. 's Cathy Bowers is a 50 yo single Caucasian female who presents to the ANH Eating Disorders Department for an evaluation and treatment recommendations for low weight.  She shared that she has recently lost a great deal of weight and is having difficulty meeting her calorie needs due to difficulties with gagging/swallowing, and aversions to specific food textures.  Specifically, since **May 2012**, she has lost 18 lbs, going from 128 lbs (BMI = 19.5, normal range) to 110.2 lbs (BMI = 16.8, underweight range) at a height of 5\'8" tall.  She has had amenorrhea for 2 months.  Her current weight is her lowest since high school, when she was a model and weighed 98 lbs (BMI = 14.9, underweight range).  At that time, she had amenorrhea, felt pressure to be thin in order to keep her job, and most likely met criteria for frank anorexia nervosa nervosa-restricting type.\n'

For all of these cases, I was able to properly debug the expression and validate them on Reg101.

This makes me think that maybe there's a mismatch between the Python parser/version used by Reg101 and the Python version I'm using (3) - or maybe a parameter that I'm not aware of.

Anyone has a clue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use [`(?:0?[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])/(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])/(?:19\d{2}|20[0-1][0-7]|\d{2})`](https://regex101.com/r/NSUWSR/2)

Answer (score 2):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/OdSQza/2)

```
\d+/\d+(?:/\d+)?|(?:\d+ )?(?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|June?|July?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec(?:ember)?)[.,]?(?:-\d+-\d+| \d+(?:th|rd|st|nd)?,? \d+| \d+)|\d{4}
```

---

### Results

#### Input

> 04/20/2009; 04/20/09; 4/20/09; 4/3/09 Mar-20-2009; Mar 20, 2009; March
>   20, 2009; Mar. 20, 2009; Mar 20 2009; 20 Mar 2009; 20 March 2009; 20
>   Mar. 2009; 20 March, 2009 Mar 20th, 2009; Mar 21st, 2009; Mar 22nd,
>   2009 Feb 2009; Sep 2009; Oct 2010 (shall be parsed to 02/01/2009,
>   09/01/2009 etc) 6/2008; 12/2009 (shall be parsed to 06/01/2008 etc).
>   2009; 2010 (shall be parsed to 01/01/2009 and 01/01/2010) AFeb 1977:
>   Symmes Hospital\n NV fire fighter died Sep 2007 while working. Was
>   friend from deployment to San Marino and trainings for years prior.
>   Still troubling to pt. Didn't go to his funeral. Spiritual/Religion:
>   's Cathy Bowers is a 50 yo single Caucasian female who presents to the
>   ANH Eating Disorders Department for an evaluation and treatment
>   recommendations for low weight. She shared that she has recently lost
>   a great deal of weight and is having difficulty meeting her calorie
>   needs due to difficulties with gagging/swallowing, and aversions to
>   specific food textures. Specifically, since May 2012, she has lost 18
>   lbs, going from 128 lbs (BMI = 19.5, normal range) to 110.2 lbs (BMI =
>   16.8, underweight range) at a height of 5\'8" tall. She has had amenorrhea for 2 months. Her current weight is her lowest since high
>   school, when she was a model and weighed 98 lbs (BMI = 14.9,
>   underweight range). At that time, she had amenorrhea, felt pressure to
>   be thin in order to keep her job, and most likely met criteria for
>   frank anorexia nervosa nervosa-restricting type.

#### Output

Below shows matches only.

```
04/20/2009
04/20/09
4/20/09
4/3/09
Mar-20-2009
Mar 20, 2009
March 20, 2009
Mar. 20, 2009
Mar 20 2009
20 Mar 2009
20 March 2009
20 Mar. 2009
20 March, 2009
Mar 20th, 2009
Mar 21st, 2009
Mar 22nd, 2009
Feb 2009
Sep 2009
Oct 2010
02/01/2009
09/01/2009
6/2008
12/2009
06/01/2008
2009
2010
01/01/2009
01/01/2010
Feb 1977
Sep 2007
May 2012
```

---

### Explanation

- Match either of the following options

  - `\d+/\d+(?:/\d+)?` Match one or more digits followed by `/` followed by one or more digits, followed by the possibility of another `/` with one or more digits
  - `(?:\d+ )?(?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|June?|July?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec(?:ember)?)[.,]?(?:-\d+-\d+| \d+(?:th|rd|st|nd)?,? \d+| \d+)` Match a possibility of one or more digits followed by a space, followed by month names (or their short forms), followed by the possibility of a dot `.` or comma `,`, followed by either `-` digits `-` digits; *or* space  digits with the possibility of `th`, `rd`, `st`, or `nd` and the possibility of a following comma, then a space and more digits; *or* a space followed by a digit
  - `\d{4}` Match any digit 4 times (this is for single years, but may catch other valid numbers, you may need to change this to your needs. Adding word boundaries as `\b\d{4}\b` might be a good first step.