# Date and time column has mixed format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am having some issue in formatting the date and time. I have data file that contains date and time. Below is the sample date that represents part of my data.

```
data = pd.DataFrame()
data['Date'] = ['01 Jul 2014 - Qualification','30 Sep 2014 - Group Stage','17 Mar 2015 - Play Offs',' 19:00:00']
data ['ID'] = [1,2,3,4]
```

I created a new columns and tried to format using **datetime** as follow:

```
data['date1'] = pd.to_datetime(data.Date,errors = 'coerce')
```

I got all NaT in date time. I also wanted to create two new columns such as Time column and stage to represent the time and the game stage.

How can I proceed with the issue?

Comment: can you post the sample output...confused what you actually want!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Date` column has text that is other than just date/time. You cannot convert it to datetime object as it is. You need to isolate the date/time part of the text from the rest of it. To do this, you can split on `-` and expand to get the Stage text and date in separate columns of a temp dataframe `df_temp` and then use these columns to assign & create each in your existing dataframe:

```
In [27]: df_temp = data['Date'].str.split('-', expand=True)

In [28]: data['date1'] = df_temp[0]

In [29]: data['stage'] = df_temp[1]

In [30]: data
Out[30]:
                          Date  ID         date1           stage
0  01 Jul 2014 - Qualification   1  01 Jul 2014    Qualification
1    30 Sep 2014 - Group Stage   2  30 Sep 2014      Group Stage
2      17 Mar 2015 - Play Offs   3  17 Mar 2015        Play Offs
3                     19:00:00   4      19:00:00            None

In [31]: data['date1'] = pd.to_datetime(data.date1,errors = 'coerce')

In [32]: data
Out[32]:
                          Date  ID      date1           stage
0  01 Jul 2014 - Qualification   1 2014-07-01   Qualification
1    30 Sep 2014 - Group Stage   2 2014-09-30     Group Stage
2      17 Mar 2015 - Play Offs   3 2015-03-17       Play Offs
3                     19:00:00   4        NaT            None
```

Comment: Hi amanb, Thanks for the prompt reply and sorry for my delay to reply. How about the time column? I like to create a new column that represents the time.

Comment: You can create the new column just like the others, but I could not find time specific informaton in either of the existing columns. If you have time data as a list for eg., then just do `df['Time'] = #time data`

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex here with [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/47656743
pat = r'(\d+/\d+(?:/\d+)?|(?:\d+ )?(?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|June?|July?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec(?:ember)?)[.,]?(?:-\d+-\d+| \d+(?:th|rd|st|nd)?,? \d+| \d+)|\d{4})'
```

---

```
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/46069885
pat = r'((?:\d{,2}\s)?(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[a-z]*(?:-|\.|\s|,)\s?\d{,2}[a-z]*(?:-|,|\s)?\s?\d{2,4})'

s = data['Date'].str.extract(pat, expand=False)
data['date1']  = pd.to_datetime(s, errors = 'coerce')
print (data)
                          Date  ID      date1
0  01 Jul 2014 - Qualification   1 2014-07-01
1    30 Sep 2014 - Group Stage   2 2014-09-30
2      17 Mar 2015 - Play Offs   3 2015-03-17
3                     19:00:00   4        NaT
```

Comment: Hi Jez, Thanks a lot for the prompt reply to my query. Sorry for the delay in reply. 
How about the game stage and time column? Thanks